# Is it possible to prefetch database object from auth/custom annotation in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, interceptor

I have the following endpoint in my Spring MVC controller:

```
@RestController
public class ToolsController {

    @GetMapping("/v1/auth-check/....id....")
    @RolesAllowed(...)
    @MyCustomPermissions(...)
    public MyResult checkAuth(...., int databaseId, ....) {
```

Here roles allowed is a standard annotation, which checks with user data and prevent method from being called without permissions.

Now I want additionally to check permissions with the help of a data, which is contained in a database object, identified by parameter `databaseId`. Can I read this object from somewhere so that my annotation also prevent method from being called?

I can parse request separately in `HandlerInterceptorAdapter#preHandle`

This is bad because I will duplicate Spring's work. Are there any other mechanisms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the object you're referring to as *"database object"* is the result returned by `checkAuth()` then sure you can examine its contents [`@PostAuthorize`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/access/prepost/PostAuthorize.html). If a SpEl expression provided as an argument would not match, then request processing would fail with an exception.

It would look like this:

```
@PostAuthorize("returnObject.databaseId ... <- your-conditional-logic-here")
```

**Reminder:** to make this annotation enabled, `prePostEnabled` attribute of the `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` (*which annotates configuration class*) needs to be set to `true` (*I guess you're aware of this, but a random reader might be not*):

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
```

In case if you didn't refer to the resulting object, then you can retrieve this *"database object"* right inside the SpEl-expression because we're free to use any Beans and invoke their methods. So it still can be using `@PostAuthorize`.

Also, it's worth noticing:

- That it's better keep SpEl-expression as simple as possible, since its hard to test.
- `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` is deprecated since release version `5.3`, so it's not a great alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Use `@PreAuthorize` which allows you to define a SpEL to refer to a method in any bean that will be executed before a method is called for permission checking. The permission checking method should return a boolean which true means allow while false means disallow.

In that SpEL , you can use `@bean` to refer to a bean and use `#foo` or `@P` to access the parameters of the method that `@PreAuthorize` protects.(docs at [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html5/#access-control-using-preauthorize-and-postauthorize))

Something like :

```java
@GetMapping("/v1/auth-check/....id....")
@PreAuthorize("@authzService.isAllow(#databaseId)")
public MyResult checkAuth(...., int databaseId, ....) {

}
```

which will look for a bean which the name is `authzService` and execute its `isAllow()` for permission checking.

```java
@Service
public class AuthzService{

    public boolean isAllow(int databaseId){
        /******************************************
          Do the checking here....
          Use SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() to access the current user object such that you can check their roles. 
         ******************************************/
    }
}
```